# "Outer" Butterfly Theorem

Tags: geometry

Problem 2.8.1 from Coxeter and Greitzer's Geometry Revisited book is a variation on the Butterfly Theorem. For background, the Butterfly Theorem itself is: Through the midpoint M of a chord PQ of a circle, any other chords AB and CD are drawn; chords AD and BC meet PQ at points X and Y. Then M is the midpoint of XY. This diagram gives the proof the book gives for the regular butterfly (you may need to zoom in on this and the other diagram
in order to read the labels and text):

[image: Butterfly Theorem]

Problem 2.8.1 in Geometry Revisited, that I'm calling the "Outer Butterfly", is "Extend AC and BD to intersect the extension of PQ at two points which, like X and Y, are equidistant from M".

The figure below is my solution to this, also showing in dotted lines the construction for the original butterfly theorem (few labels since the diagram is complicated enough as it is). I think my solution works, but the hint in the back of the book simply states that the proof is the same as that given in the text for the original butterfly, apart from a few changes in sign.

My question is: Can anyone supply the proof described in the book's answer. I would also appreciate any feedback on this alternative solution that I came up with:

[image: "Outer Butterfly" Theorem]

Answer (score 0):

This proof is quite similar to the one in the book. Let the chords $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at $M$ such that the extension of $AD$ and $BC$ intersect with $PQ$ outside of the circle at points $X$ and $Y$, resp. Also drop perpendiculars $x_1$ and $y_1$ from $X$ and $Y$ to $AB$; $x_2$ and $y_2$ from $X$ and $Y$ to $CD$.
Let $x = XM$, $y=MY$, $a = PM = MQ$. As in *Geometry Revisited*, $Ax_1 \sim Cy_2$, $Dx_2 \sim By_1$, $My_2 \sim Mx_2$, and $My_1 \sim Mx_1$. Thus $$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{x_1}{y_1} = \frac{x_2}{y_2}$$ $$ \frac{x_1}{y_2} = \frac{AX}{CY}$$ $$\frac{x_2}{y_1} = \frac{XD}{BY}$$
So that $$\frac{x^2}{y^2} = \frac{x_1}{y_1} \frac{x_2}{y_2} = \frac{x_2}{y_1} \frac{x_1}{y_2} = \frac{XD}{BY} \frac{AX}{CY} = \frac{XQ \times XP}{YQ \times YP} = \frac{(x-a)(x+a)}{(y-a)(y+a)}= \frac{x^2-a^2}{y^2-a^2} = \frac{-a^2}{-a^2}=1$$

[This is the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHzS1.png)